# Make same active button after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now, I have two buttons that each button have different views.

```
 <div style="margin-top:-25px;margin-left:105px;">
      <p style="color:black;"><b>View In : </b></p>
      <div class="btnContainer" id="btnContainer">
         <button class="lists active" onclick="gridView()"> Grid</button>
         <button class="lists" onclick="listView()" style="margin-left:-4px;"> List</button> 
      </div>
 </div>

  <div class="row" id="pading1">

      <!------------- Card Position 1 ----------------->
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="pading2">

      <!------------- Card Position 2 ----------------->
  </div>
```

Here's the css script to styling the button

```
  /* Style the buttons grid */
.lists {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
}
.lists:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.lists.active {
    background-color: #01b1ea;
    color: white;
}
.btnContainer{
    background-color:transparent;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:-35px;
    margin-left:70px;
}
```

Here's js script to switch the view every page

```
    <!------------------- Switch Padding Button Grid Maps ------------------->
    <script>
      function listView(){
        $("#pading1").hide();
        $("#pading2").show();
        $(".search-container").hide();
      }

      function gridView(){
        $("#pading1").show();
        $("#pading2").hide();
      }

      var container = document.getElementById("btnContainer");
      var btns = container.getElementsByClassName("lists");
      for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
           var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
           current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
           this.className += " active";
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Right now, every I reload the page it still going to `grid` view as I set `grid` view is the default.

I want to ask, when I in `list` view and I refresh the web, how to make the `button` `active` is still in the `list` view ?

Thank you

Comment: You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) .

Comment: Hi @Swati Do you have any more example for localStorage ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either by setting a sessionStorage / localStorage or a cookie. This is a working example using sessionStorage:

```
      // Check what type of view we have setup
  if(sessionStorage.view == 'list') {
    listView();
  }
  else {
    gridView();
  }
  
 function listView(){
    $("#pading1").hide();
    $("#pading2").show();
    $(".search-container").hide();
    sessionStorage.view = "list";
  }

  function gridView(){
    $("#pading1").show();
    $("#pading2").hide();
    sessionStorage.view = "grid";
  }

  var container = document.getElementById("btnContainer");
  var btns = container.getElementsByClassName("lists");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
       current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
       this.className += " active";
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi @ShiZniT, It's working, but when reload, the button active is still in default. I think I need to modify the `for....` function, do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well.

```
style="@if(request()->get('btn') == Grid ) <?php echo 'background-color: #2B2540' ?> @endif" data-val="Grid"
```